# Drupal 8 contact form attachment removed

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, contact-form

I've attached a file field to a job application form (contact form) so visitors are able to upload an attachment that is stored in the private file system. It does work, however the file is removed after a couple of hours. I think this is caused by Drupal orphaned files cleanup (see /admin/config/media/file-system).

One possible solution seems to be to make use of the Webform module (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) instead of the core contact form. But is s there a way to prevent the file from being automatically removed or to actually attach it to the email that is sent?

Comment: I don't have a write up on how to fully integrate this, but, have you looked at the Swiftmailer module to send emails?  You can write swiftmailer twig templates for the sent email as html.  Files should be attached.

Comment: I've installed the swiftmailer module, but it did not attach attachments to the email.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue with inline images uploaded to custom blocks. Under admin/config/media/file-system you'll see a dropdown for "Delete temporary files after": Select "Never".

Comment: I think it is not correct that those uploaded file are marked as temporary. The same applies to an attachment after a form submission. I therefore think not deleting "temporary files" is not the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create an issue at [drupal.org](http://drupal.org), or use the [hook_ENTITY_TYPE](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.2.x)_insert to update the temporary state to a permanent file.